# Dock stack with multiple folders

Tags: macos, dock, folders

I like to have a stack in my dock with my applications folder in it, but some applications (especially games installed by Steam) appear in my `~/Applications` folder, instead of my `/Applications` folder.

Is it possible to have a stack displaying the merged contents of both folders?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, no.

You CAN create Aliases of the two folders, then drop them into another folder (which you then drag to the dock) but this only gives you those folders in a dock folder...

BUT... you can have them operate within one folder.. And you might like this option...

1. create a folder that you'll use to drop into the dock.
2. make aliases of both the ~/App folder and the /App folder
3. drop them in that folder
4. put it in the dock
5. right-click on it and mark it as a List.

Now it'll allow you to "spring into" each of those sub folders on the fly....

look at this URL: http://www.macworld.com/article/1160337/dock_access.html